# Таймер на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, denwer

Недавно я попросил одного человека сделать вывод таймера на JavaScript. Он сделал все быстро и толково, но время отображается с небольшими погрешностями, причем в разных профайлах (разных людей запустивших таймер) разница во времени (относительно правильного отсчета) разная, поэтому выявить какую-либо ошибку я не могу.

```
function clock_update (ss)
{
    date1 = new Date ();//1307453901000
    date2 = new Date (ss);

    diff  = new Date();
    diff.setTime (date1.getTime() - ss*1000);
    timediff = diff.getTime();
    years = Math.floor (timediff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
    timediff -= years * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
    months = Math.floor (timediff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
    timediff -= months * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
    weeks = Math.floor (timediff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
    days = Math.floor(timediff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    timediff -= days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    hours = Math.floor(timediff / (1000 * 60 * 60)); 
    timediff -= hours * (1000 * 60 * 60);
    minutes = Math.floor(timediff / (1000 * 60)); 
    timediff -= minutes * (1000 * 60);
    seconds = Math.floor(timediff / 1000);
    timediff -= seconds * 1000;

    if (hours < 10)  hours = '0' + hours;
    if (minutes < 10)  minutes = '0' + minutes;
    if (seconds < 10)  seconds = '0' + seconds;

    document.getElementById ('times').innerHTML = '';

    if (years>0) document.getElementById ('times').innerHTML += years + 'г. ';
    if (months>0) document.getElementById ('times').innerHTML += months + ' м. ';
    if (days>0) document.getElementById ('times').innerHTML += days + ' д.<br>';

    document.getElementById ('times').innerHTML += hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + '';
}
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите ошибку. Нужно, чтобы второй файл на JavaScript, показывал в точности то же время, что и файл `ajax/doit.php`

**Добавлено.**

Вот два примера с двумя разными профайлами (пользователями, запустившими таймер):

1) Таймер на сайте (он работает на `ajax/doit.php`) показывает время:
3г.2м.21д.
00:11:03

таймер на *Денвере* с кодом на JavaScript (второй код в моем вопросе):
3г.2м.21д
23:11:03
Разница 23 часа

2) Таймер на сайте:
1г.10м.28д
00.55.17

таймер на *Денвере*:
1г.11м.2д
00.55.17

В первом случае таймер на JavaScript (на *Денвере*) убегает на 23 часа, во втором - на 4 суток (если в мес 30 дней).
Если на *Денвере* убрать `jquery.js` (в нем вписан код выведения таймера JavaScript) и поставить `jquery.js` с путем, указывающим на `ajax/doit.php` и саму эту папку поставить, то время будет абсолютно совпадать с тем, что на сайте в обоих профайлах.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос образец вывода времени в первом и втором случае. В чем разница?

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку разница в значениях для первого и второго случая кратна часам, то практически наверняка все дело в часовых поясах. Для первого случая расчет времени идет целиком на сервере и часовой пояс всегда один и тот же, а для второго случая расчет идет частично на основе времени клиента и частично на основе времени сервера. Следующая строка кода для каждого клиента получает свое значение в зависимости от часового пояса:

```
date1 = new Date ();
```

Нужно либо сохранять на сервере время клиента, либо передавать в JavaScript с сервера и время запуска, и текущее время.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы просто не сохранять в MySQL, например, дату нажатия на кнопку. А при обращении к сайту просто брать дату из базы и сравнивать с текущей... Потом просто сделать посекундный отсчет уже на клиентском компе... Преимущество в том, что понадобится тупо работающий таймер и все. Сохраняем в MySQL всего 1 раз.

Comment: Зачем обращаться каждую секунду к серверу? при наплыве пользователей он треснет. это не рационально просто.
ошибка скрипта заключается в том что время различается на пару секунд? ну этому есть обьяснение... все мы знаем про весокосный год, про то что в месяцах не ровно по 30 дней и про то что во дне не ровно 24 часа, а примерно 23,54. в народе принято округлять... погрешности выходят из-за вычислений

Comment: Запятая сбила с толку) Думал, как это аж почти на полчаса меньше)) Вообще 23:56:04 или 23,934 =)